# How to Fix the Wavelength of a Sine Wave With Matplotlib and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to graph a sine wave using numpy and matplotlib. Although the amplitude of the wave (1 by default) is correct, the wave's wavelength should measure at a length of $2 \pi$. As can be seen in the image below, the sine wave's wavelength is around 60.

[Sine Wave Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG28Y.png).

My code for this is as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('Solarize_Light2')

plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)

x = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)

plt.grid(True)

amp = float(input('Amplitude of sinusoidal wave: '))
y = amp * np.sin(x)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)

plt.plot(y,color='b')
plt.title(f"f(x)={amp}sin(x)")


plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')

plt.show()
```

I tried adjusting the `x = np.arange()` value but didn't seem to get any results from that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is two-fold:

(1) Your grid. If you want to look at the function in terms of its cycles, you need to plot relative to at least a half cycle (pi). You can do this by creating a grid and choosing how many half cycles you want to see (2) and multiplying the resulting grid by pi. This is done by `np.linspace(0,2,1000)*np.pi` (or `arange` but I like `linspace`).

(2) You are not plotting any x-values. By default, if you only supply one array to the `plt.plot` function, `matplotlib` will display the function values on the y-axis and array index on the x-axis. If we plot both the grid (scaled by pi) and your function, it lies neatly in the range `[0,2pi]`, because you are telling `matplotlib` what values the function is supposed to coincide with.

Below is the code I used:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('Solarize_Light2')


plt.ylim(-10, 10)

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)*np.pi

plt.grid(True)

amp = 1
y = amp * np.sin(x)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)

plt.plot(x/np.pi, y,color='b')
plt.title(f"f(x)={amp}*sin(x)")


plt.xlabel('x [$\\pi$ units]')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

np.sin(x) documentary [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html).

expects x to be array_like and an Angle, in radians ( rad equals 360 degrees).

try handing over

```
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 180)
```

documentary for linspace [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).